# How to send pdf files with cyrillic text in django?

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

I'm trying to generate pdf files in django and upload them. To do this, I use the reportlab library.

django v4.2.7
reportlab v 4.0.7

Here is a fragment of my code

```
def patients_report_view(request):

    title = f'Отчет Выгрузка карт {datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}'
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'filename="{title}.pdf"'
    font_path = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + '\\fonts\\DejaVuSerif.ttf'
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('DejaVuSerif', font_path, 'UTF-8'))

    p = canvas.Canvas(response)
    p.setFont('DejaVuSerif', 12)
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Привет мир.")

    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

I also installed some fonts for the Russian language, but still incomprehensible characters are displayed in the file.

## [image: Here is the result in the file]